# Folding multiple rows with openpyxl

Tags: openpyxl

Is there a way to fold multiple rows using `openpyxl`? There doesn't appear to be a row equivalent to the example found on the [openpyxl simple usage page](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html).

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.Workbook(True)
ws = wb.create_sheet()
ws.column_dimensions.group('A','D', hidden=True)
wb.save('group.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, there isn't an equivalent but rows are slightly easier to deal with because they are always there, `ColumnDimensions` are created on demand. Simply set the rows you want to hidden.

Eg. to hide rows 5 to 9:

```
for idx in range(5, 10):
    ws.row_dimensions[idx].hidden = True
```

Comment: Thanks. In the loop I also added `ws.row_dimensions[idx].outlineLevel = 1` to get the same behavior as the column example.

Comment: Is there anything else I should do after the ws.row_dimensions[idx].hidden = True? The line is executing, but when I open the existing file, the rows are not hidden.

Answer (score 7):

I was searching for this and only found my own answer about doing the same for columns!  https://stackoverflow.com/a/60214627

Looks like there are two modes with different APIs : 1. "Grab Handle"  (-) on top, and 2. Grab handle on bottom.  Each mode has a different strange "off by one" behavior as shown below.

Order counts! You need to define the outer level before the inner.

Example code for wanting three levels of outline.

- Level 1 (outermost) - Rows 2-25
- Level 2 (middlemost) - Rows 4-9
- Level 3 (innermost) - Rows 6-7

[image: Google Sheets screenshot of output]

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.active
for i in range(1, 25+1):
  ws.append([i])

# Expand handle at bottom
# ws.sheet_properties.outlinePr.summaryBelow = True
# ws.row_dimensions.group(2, 25-1, outline_level=1)
# ws.row_dimensions.group(4, 9-1, outline_level=2)
# ws.row_dimensions.group(6, 7-1, outline_level=3)

# Expand handle at top
# NOTE: Order counts!
ws.sheet_properties.outlinePr.summaryBelow = False
ws.row_dimensions.group(2+1, 25, outline_level=1)
ws.row_dimensions.group(4+1, 9, outline_level=2)
ws.row_dimensions.group(6+1, 7, outline_level=3)

wb.save('testrows.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do it using row_dimensions.group method

```
from openpyxl import Workbook

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.create_sheet()
ws.column_dimensions.group("A", "D", hidden=True)
ws.row_dimensions.group(1, 5, hidden=True)
wb.save("group.xlsx")
```